# Auto-incrementing a key in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, plist, auto-increment, nsmutabledictionary

I want to auto-incrementing a key and at to a NSMutableDictionary.

I tried to do it but it wasn't work :

```
NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

int testAutoIndex = 0;
[array setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:testAutoIndex++] forKey:@"index"];
[array release];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you posted creates an array, puts a value in the array, and then destroys the array. There's no point to this.

Comment: Do you want an incrementing key or an incrementing value?

Comment: you are using NSMutableDictionary, if you want auto-incremented index.. you need to use NSMutableArray instead.

Comment: I want to have this:
Item 0
    index: 0 -
Item 1
    index: 1 -
Item 2
    index: 02 -
...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

int testAutoIndex = 0;
[array setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:++testAutoIndex] forKey:@"index"];
[array release];
```

Comment: I have index: 1 for each dictionary

Comment: create testAutoIndex only once for example in interface:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a dictionary with say N entries, then it is possible to do using the code

```
int N = 100; // or what ever number you want
NSArray *arrayOfObjectsYouWantToPumpIntoDictionary = ....;
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:100];

for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d"i];
    [mutableDictionary setObject:[arrayOfObjectsYouWantToPumpIntoDictionary objectAtIndex:i] forKey:];
}

// Later some where else if you want to retrieve object with key of x (x can be 1, or 2 or what ever value), you can do

 objectToBeRetrieved = [mutableDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
```